# How to convert string to date in databricks sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, date, apache-spark-sql

I have a column named opened_dt with a timestamp in string format.

```
+----------------------------+
|        opened_dt           |
+----------------------------+
| 01/01/2015 21:50:00.000000 |
+----------------------------+
```

Running

```
DESCRIBE TABLE 'myTable'
```

tells me that the column is of type string

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| col_name  | data_type | comment |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| opened_dt | string    | null    |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

What I want to do:

```
"Show me all entries starting 01.01.2019 until now".
Which I translate to "select * from 'table' where opened_dt >= 01.01.2019".
```

Following this I convert opened_dt from to date.

When using:

```
SELECT cast(opened_dt AS timestamp)
```

just gives me

```
+------------+
| opened_dt  |
+------------+
| null       |
+------------+
```

When using:

```
SELECT to_date(opened_dt AS timestamp)
```

just gives me

```
+---------------------------------+
| to_date('myTable'.`opened_dt`)  |
+---------------------------------+
| null                            |
+---------------------------------+
```

Other attemps I tried but gives false output:

```
SELECT * FROM 'myTable' WHERE opened_dt >= '01/01/2019 00:00:00.000000' 

SELECT * FROM 'myTable' WHERE opened_dt IN ('%2019%', '%2020%', '%2021%')
```

How can I convert the string to date to filter all dates younger than 01.01.2019?

I am looking for something in SQL in DATABRICKS (other answers are in spark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast to timestamp type using `to_timestamp` and providing a date format string that matches your column's date format.

```
select *
from myTable
where to_timestamp(opened_dt, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') between to_timestamp('2019-01-01') and current_timestamp()
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. I tested it with     to_timestamp('2021-03-02')     and      to_timestamp('2021-02-03')      but the output I get is "01/04/2021 16:39:00.000000"

Comment: sorry, I didn't know you have entries in the future. See edited answer? @Wondarar

Comment: me neither haha. thanks for the edit, works fine :) Meanwhile I tried another attempt "WHERE f11.opened_dt LIKE '%2019%' OR f11.opened_dt LIKE '%2020%' OR f11.opened_dt LIKE '%2021%'" but since I join 10 tables in this query it results in a major performance issue. I guess the problems are the wildcards which are mandatory though, and the amount of joined tables.